# Android memory management: Screen density, requested image sizes and available heap

Tags: android, memory-management, picasso

Guess what, another Android-Bitmap-OOM question!

**Background**

Whilst stress testing [our application](http://www.materialapp.com/) it has been noted that it is possible to max-out the app's process memory allocation after sustained, heavy usage (monkey runner like) with `OutOfMemory` exceptions being recorded within the ensuing stacktrace. The app downloads images (around 3 at a time) when a page under a `ViewPager` is selected. There can be 280+ images available for download when the length and breath of the app is exercised. The application uses [Picasso by Square](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for it's image downloading abstraction. Notably, at no point in our application's code are we manipulating Bitmaps directly...we trust that the very talented Square Inc. employees are doing it better than we can.

**Here is a picture**

The below plot shows the heap allocations over time recorded under the `dalvikvm-heap` log message. The red dots indicates a user bringing a fresh set of articles into the application in order to bolster the amount of work outstanding and stress the app...

[DALVIKVM heap allocations http://snag.gy/FgsiN.jpg](http://snag.gy/FgsiN.jpg)
*Figure 1:* Nexus One heap allocations; OOMs occur at 80MB+

**Investigation to-date**

Against a Nexus S, Nexus 4, Wildfire, HTC Incredible and a myriad of further test devices, anecdotal testing has shown the memory management to be sufficient with the DVM GC 'keeping up' with the heavy lifting work being completed by the app. However, on high end devices such as the Galaxy S II, III, IV and HTC One the OOM are prevalent. In fact given enough work to do, I would imagine all of our devices would eventually exhibit the failure.

**The question**

There is clearly a relationship between screen density (our requested image sizes are based off the size of the ImageView), the process memory allocation and the number of images at a given size that would result in the app exceeding it's heap limits. I am about to embark on quantifying this relationship but would like the SO community to cast their eyes over this problem and (a) agree or disagree that the relationship is worth making and (b) provide literature indicating how best to draw up this relationship.

It is important to note that if we destroy the image quality our OOM all disappear but alas the UX is poorer which is why we are wanting to be dicing with the most effective use of the available heap.

---

Side note: Here is the portion of code responsible for loading these images into the views that have been laid out;

```
picassoInstance.load(entry.getKey())
               .resize(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
                       imageView.getMeasuredHeight())
               .centerCrop()
               .into(imageView);
```

The 'dashing of image quality' mentioned above is simply dividing the `imageView.getMeasured...` by a number like '4'.

Comment: Picasso also provides snapshots of how much memory is used for bitmaps. How big are the images you are trying to load? Are they full screen? Even the best phones with tons of memory will crash by loading three or more images. Are you positive your view is measured before invoking Picasso? You could also try using `fit()` instead.

Comment: You may also consider exploring the `largeHeap` property if your application is very intensive on bitmaps. Picasso will adjust memory accordingly if this is enabled. The golden rule for me is decode as much as you need and never more. It seems like you are doing that. I would keep a close eye out on your usage. In the sample app for Picasso which I've tested on multiple devices I never get an OOM exception and it seems high end devices deal pretty well with cleaning up the garbage.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @dnkoutso. Picasso is performing well as far as I can tell; always recovers when OOMs do occur. I'll keep you posted on my exploits. Out of interest; should I be shutting down Picasso at any point explicitly?

Comment: We did add a `shutdown()` API in 2.0. You should invoke it when you think its necessary (e.g. user logged out?). You must invoke it against your own instance which you seem to be already using (don't use it against the static singleton `Picasso.with(...)`.

Comment: OceanLife let me know how that worked out for you or if there is anything else you want to discuss with.

Comment: We've been up late tweaking with MAT and experimenting with a number of devices. Here is how it looks; Picasso+Pure Google Android = no problems. GC is effective and OOMs are avoided. Picasso+Samsung Galaxy hardware...disaster. Very unpredicatable performance ranging from OK to crash on rendering the first few images. Providing these devices with the 'largeHeap' attribute you mentioned does avoid the OOM (The S4 allocates 528MB with large heap enabled!!). So, the sledge hammer approach works with Samsung crock. On another note, ````fit```` is ideal - exactly what I had reengineered - replaced.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to know more. Have you tried (and if its easy to do so) to use a different image lib? Some of them internally catch the OOM exceptions which is to me "meh". I think catching the OOM feels wrong and it just means that you're doing more than you're supposed to do so...but it works I guess...!

Comment: We do have a home-brew library which we moved away from owing to support issues (the chap that wrote it is a contractor and lives in Ukraine!). The downloader is pluggable with some manual DI we're doing (Haven't convinced the team to put in Dagger yet) and we've been wanting to see them side-by-side. I'll keep you informed (off on hols for 2 wks now though!)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to manage the memories allocation ,its a big issue in android as bitmaps takes lots of memories ,for that memory allocation can be reduce by following ways

1. put all those images which are huge in size to assets folder instead of putting them in drawabable folder . because drawable resources takes memory for caching them .if you load from asset folder the image will not cache .and  will takes less memory .

   1. study Lrucache which use  for efficient memory management .
   2. put resources in tiny formats  for that check [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.com/)
   3. if your images are too large in resolution , then try to use SVG files for images and load SVG file instead of image . check this [SVG FOR ANDROID](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/)

finally i am not very good in English hope it may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old but I also had this issue recently. Maybe this will help someone else.
General Overview of this massive thread/What helped me.

-Make sure you are using a Singleton Instance of Picasso

-Use fit()

-For large Images or many Images or when used in a FragmentPager/StatePager you should probably use skipmemorycache() and/or largeHeap declaration

Read the thread for more tips. At the time this question was posted nobody had posted this issue on picassos github.

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/305